# Display only the current user logged in records in the index view in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, filtering

How can I display the currently logged in user's records in the index view? I don't want them to see other users record, I just want them to see their own added records in the database. I already have implemented identity authentication and verification so users can have their own accounts. Please help me modify my code. I can't see any resources about this problem. I do not have ApplicationUser so I used IdentityUser instead.

This is currently my class model:

```
 public class CommitmentForm
 {
    [Key]
    public int CommitmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? OrganizationName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? AdvicerName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? ContactNo { get; set; }

    public int CollegeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CollegeId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public College College { get; set; }

    public int AcademicRankId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AcademicRankId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public AcademicRank AcademicRank { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "School Year")]
    public int SchoolYear { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Year;
 }
```

This is currently my View Model:

```
public class CommitmentFormVM
{
    public CommitmentForm CommitmentForm { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CollegeList { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AcademicRankList { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller Actions:

```
public class CommitmentFormController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public CommitmentFormController(ApplicationDbContext db, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _db = db;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    //public IActionResult Index()
    //{
    //    string userId = Commonism.getUserId(this.User);

    //    var User = _db.Users.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == userId);

    //    if (User == null)
    //    {
    //        return NotFound();
    //    }

    //    var currentUserCommitments = _db.CommitmentForms.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).ToList();

    //    return View(currentUserCommitments);
    //}

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _unitOfWork.Commitment == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var commitmentObj = _unitOfWork.Commitment.Get(u => u.CommitmentId == id, includeProperties: "College,AcademicRank");

        if (commitmentObj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(commitmentObj);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert(int? id)
    {
        CommitmentFormVM cmVM = new CommitmentFormVM
        {
            CollegeList = _unitOfWork.College.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.CollegeName,
                Value = u.CollegeId.ToString()
            }),

            AcademicRankList = _unitOfWork.AcademicRank.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.RankName,
                Value = u.AcademicRankId.ToString()
            }),

            CommitmentForm = new CommitmentForm()
        };

        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            // create
            return View(cmVM);
        }
        else
        {
            // update
            cmVM.CommitmentForm = _unitOfWork.Commitment.Get(u => u.CommitmentId == id);
            return View(cmVM);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert(CommitmentFormVM commitmentFormVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (commitmentFormVM.CommitmentForm.CommitmentId == 0)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Commitment.Add(commitmentFormVM.CommitmentForm);
                TempData["success"] = "Commitment Form added successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                _unitOfWork.Commitment.Update(commitmentFormVM.CommitmentForm);
                TempData["success"] = "Commitment Form updated successfully";
            }
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = commitmentFormVM.CommitmentForm.CommitmentId });
        }
        else
        {
            commitmentFormVM.CollegeList = _unitOfWork.College.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.CollegeName,
                Value = u.CollegeId.ToString()
            });
            commitmentFormVM.AcademicRankList = _unitOfWork.AcademicRank.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.RankName,
                Value = u.AcademicRankId.ToString()
            });

            return View(commitmentFormVM);
        }         
    }

    public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        CommitmentFormVM cmVM = new()
        {
            CollegeList = _unitOfWork.College.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.CollegeName,
                Value = u.CollegeId.ToString()
            }),
            AcademicRankList = _unitOfWork.AcademicRank.
            GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = u.RankName,
                Value = u.AcademicRankId.ToString()
            }),
            CommitmentForm = new CommitmentForm(),
        };

        // delete
        cmVM.CommitmentForm = _unitOfWork.Commitment.Get(u => u.CommitmentId == id);
        return View(cmVM);
        
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult DeleteCategory(int? id)
    {
        if (_unitOfWork == null)
        {
            return Problem("Entity set 'IUnitOfWork'  is null.");
        }
        CommitmentForm? category = _unitOfWork.Commitment.Get(u => u.CommitmentId == id);
        if (category != null)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commitment.Remove(category);
        }

        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        TempData["success"] = "Commitment Form deleted successfully"; //for toaster before redirecting
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

I commented the Index Action cause I don't know what to do.

Here is my Upsert view if ever I need to change something in there:

```
@model CommitmentFormVM;

<div class="college-create-container" style="margin-top:10rem">

    <div class="cf-form-container">

        <div class="cf-logo-container">
            @(Model.CommitmentForm.CommitmentId != 0 ? "Update" : "Create") Commitment Form
        </div>

        <form method="post" class="cf-form">
            <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.CommitmentId" hidden />

            <div class="cf-form-group">
                <label for="orgName">Organization Name</label>
                <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.OrganizationName" type="text" id="orgName" placeholder="College Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.OrganizationName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-form-group">
                <label for="advName">Advicer Name</label>
                <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.AdvicerName" type="text" id="advName" placeholder="College Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.AdvicerName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-form-group">
                <label for="address">Home Address</label>
                <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.HomeAddress" type="text" id="address" placeholder="College Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.HomeAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-form-group">
                <label for="cn">Contact Number</label>
                <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.ContactNo" type="text" id="cn" placeholder="College Name">
                <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.ContactNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-form-group">
                <label for="sy">School Year</label>
                <input asp-for="CommitmentForm.SchoolYear" type="text" id="sy" disabled>
                <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.SchoolYear" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="cf-row">
                <div class="cf-form-group">
                    <label for="college">College</label>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.CommitmentForm.CollegeId" asp-items="@Model.CollegeList" id="college" class="form-select">
                        <option disabled selected>--Select College--</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.CollegeId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="cf-form-group">
                    <label for="ar">Academic Rank</label>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.CommitmentForm.AcademicRankId" asp-items="@Model.AcademicRankList" id="ar" class="form-select">
                        <option disabled selected>--Select Academic Rank--</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="CommitmentForm.AcademicRankId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @if(Model.CommitmentForm.CommitmentId != 0)
            {
                <button class="cf-form-submit-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button class="cf-form-submit-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
            }
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

(I already get the current logged in user ID and displayed in in a form. It is visible before i click the submit button, but after that, the userId disappears which led to `modelstate.isValid` to be false and not proceed to the index view)
The code above in upsert httppost direct to details action because I don't still have a view for index, but what I want is to navigate them to the index first after creating a record and there they can see their own created records.

(I expect that once a user created a record, they will be navigated to index view where the list of their own created records are shown. They should not see other users records)

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  When you uncomment your `Index` action, in what way does it not work as expected?  What debugging have you done and which specific operation isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: here's the problem. When i uncomment the index action that was supposed to filter all the records in the database that are only created by the current logged in user. For example, user 1 logged in to the system, then he created a record. He should be navigated to the index view after he created the record. In the index view, he should see the list of records that he created, only the records he created not the records created by other user. The same goes with user2, user3, and others.

Comment: That doesn't describe a *problem*, that describes functionality.  When you implemented that functionality, did you encounter a *problem* in that implementation?  In what specific way is your code not working as expected and what debugging have you done?

Comment: I've tried using _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User) inside index, create HTTPGET, and create HTTPPOST. I stored it in a variable then check if the UserId property I have inside CommitmentForm class is equal to that variable. I also set the value of UserId property of CommitmentForm to the variable equal to _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User) before checking if model state is valid, to ensure that no property in my CommitmentForm class is null that can result to ModelState.IsValid to being false.

Comment: I tried adding a debugging point in ModelState.IsValid in Upsert HTTPPost action after all those configurations but then it seems like the value set to UserId property is temporary and vanish after clicking the submit button in Upsert view, that results to the UserId property to be null and lead to ModelState equal to Invalid. That's what I noticed.

Comment: The UserId property of CommitmentForm class that I am saying has a type of string. I didnt include it in the code as I remove it and just ask if someone can correct it. What should I add or change on those codes, should I need to have a foreign key relationship with the IdentityUser class?

Comment: Sorry, but your description of the problem is *all over the place*.  Narrow it to one specific piece of functionality that you are working on and one specific problem that you are observing in that attempt.  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , you should make sure there is the relation ship between the CommitmentForm and the ApplicationUser(custom identity user) which makes the one to one or one to many for them.

Like below:

public class CommitmentForm
{
[Key]
public int CommitmentId { get; set; }

```
[Required]
public string? OrganizationName { get; set; }

[Required]
public string? AdvicerName { get; set; }

[Required]
public string? HomeAddress { get; set; }

[Required]
public string? ContactNo { get; set; }

public int CollegeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("CollegeId")]
[ValidateNever]
public College College { get; set; }

public int AcademicRankId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AcademicRankId")]
[ValidateNever]
public AcademicRank AcademicRank { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "School Year")]
public int SchoolYear { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Year;

public ApplicationUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
```

}

Then you could create a custom identity user like below:

Create a new class:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
      public CommitmentForm CommitmentForm { get; set; }
  }
```

Modify the dbcontext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
     public DbSet<CommitmentForm> CommitmentForms { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Then we have the relationship for this two class.

Then inside the view, you could query the ID to the index view, like below:

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
 


    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
     
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var currentUserCommitments = new List<CommitmentForm>();
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           currentUserCommitments = _db.CommitmentForms.Where(u => u.IdentityUser.UserName ==  User.Identity
```

.Name).ToList();
}

```
        return View(currentUserCommitments);
    }
```

Then for the model validate failed issue, you need use debug tool to debug which property caused the model fail, and if some fired is required inside the CommitmentFormVM, like application user Id, you could create a hidden field to store it.

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="CommitmentForm.IdentityUser.Id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16) in the database. Even reading the database documentation may give you a better idea on how to implement this in .Net.